# Why image in VirtualBox 5.2.18 doesn't work with latest VirtualBox 6.0.8?

Tags: virtualbox

In Ubuntu, VirtualBox installation via `apt install virtualbox` only offers the old version v5.2.18.

```
user@linux:~$ apt show virtualbox
Package: virtualbox
Version: 5.2.18-dfsg-2~ubuntu18.04.5
Priority: optional
Section: multiverse/misc
Origin: Ubuntu
```

Initially, I was using this version for a while.

Then, I decided to download and install the latest one (v6.0.8) available [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads).

```
user@linux:~$ sha256sum virtualbox-6.0_6.0.8-130520~Ubuntu~bionic_amd64.deb 
17f1a24848dcf8ec1025790d35281f7f38b2c98740ddbccac6259a0f4c1786f7  virtualbox-6.0_6.0.8-130520~Ubuntu~bionic_amd64.deb
user@linux:~$
```

Initially, I was not able to install the latest one.

```
user@linux:~$ sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-6.0_6.0.8-130520~Ubuntu~bionic_amd64.deb 
[sudo] password for user: 
Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox-6.0.
dpkg: considering removing virtualbox in favour of virtualbox-6.0 ...
dpkg: no, cannot proceed with removal of virtualbox (--auto-deconfigure will help):
 virtualbox-qt depends on virtualbox (= 5.2.18-dfsg-2~ubuntu18.04.5)
  virtualbox is to be removed.

dpkg: regarding virtualbox-6.0_6.0.8-130520~Ubuntu~bionic_amd64.deb containing virtualbox-6.0:
 virtualbox-6.0 conflicts with virtualbox
  virtualbox (version 5.2.18-dfsg-2~ubuntu18.04.5) is present and installed.

dpkg: error processing archive virtualbox-6.0_6.0.8-130520~Ubuntu~bionic_amd64.deb (--install):
 conflicting packages - not installing virtualbox-6.0
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-6.0_6.0.8-130520~Ubuntu~bionic_amd64.deb
user@linux:~$
```

Removing `VirtualBox 5.2.18` fixed the issue

```
user@linux:~$ sudo apt remove virtualbox
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libgsoap-2.8.60 virtualbox-dkms
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  virtualbox virtualbox-qt
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 108 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 229334 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing virtualbox-qt (5.2.18-dfsg-2~ubuntu18.04.5) ...
Removing virtualbox (5.2.18-dfsg-2~ubuntu18.04.5) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.9-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
user@linux:~$
```

Then, I proceed with the installation again without any problem.

```
user@linux:~$ sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-6.0_6.0.8-130520~Ubuntu~bionic_amd64.deb 
(Reading database ... 229023 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack virtualbox-6.0_6.0.8-130520~Ubuntu~bionic_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox-6.0 (6.0.8-130520~Ubuntu~bionic) over (6.0.8-130520~Ubuntu~bionic) ...
Setting up virtualbox-6.0 (6.0.8-130520~Ubuntu~bionic) ...
addgroup: The group `vboxusers' already exists as a system group. Exiting.
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.23) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.9-2) ...
user@linux:~$
```

Unfortunately, none of my previous image work with the new VirtualBox.

[image]

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine Ubuntu-18.04-Server.

The virtual machine 'Ubuntu-18.04-Server' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: MachineWrap
Interface: IMachine {5047460a-265d-4538-b23e-ddba5fb84976}
```

What happened and how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem installing virtualbox 6 while having virtualbox 5 already installed. Before installing virtualbox-6.0, I just tried

```
sudo apt remove virtualbox
```

and then

```
sudo apt install virtualbox-6.0
```

but when trying "apt upgrade" lead to:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
virtualbox-6.0 : Conflicts: virtualbox
                 Conflicts: virtualbox-qt but 5.2.18-dfsg-2~ubuntu18.04.5 is to be installed
```

so I realized there was some package not correclty removed.

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge virtualbox*
sudo apt install virtualbox-6.0
```

finally worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

> "The Virtualbox kernel module does not match this version of
>   virtualbox"

I think that is explained quite well.

Your installed virtualbox kernel module is still the 5.x.x one. But your installed virtualbox version is 6.x.x. There is a **mismatch**.

## Unload the modules

You can manually **unload** the module(s).

```
sudo modprobe -r vboxpci
sudo modprobe -r vboxnetadp
sduo mdoprobe -r vboxnetflt
[...]
sudo modprobe -r vboxdrv
```

Note: don't mind if modprobe reports module not found

Then relaunch virtualbox.

## Reboot

... or (**not and**) you can simply reboot.